# Will Allah punish me if I am married to a man who won’t pray?

Tags: salat, nikah, husband-wife, punishment

Will Allah (swt) punish me if I am married to a man who doesn’t pray 5 times a day?

I love my husband very much and it was my choice to marry him. He keeps on saying he will pray when it will be the right time for it. Simply delaying his prayers

Comment: tell him that Allah will ask him in the day on judgement when no person can help

Answer (score 2):

If he does not pray, then it is his fault, not yours. You will not be punished for his sins and he will not be punished for your sins.

Answer (score 1):

According to the extra information in comments above, he believes in Islam and knows that praying is a must, but commit sin by not praying ... This way he is not a Kafir, so that the marriage is not a sin and you will not be punished for marrying with him ... But then he is commiting a sin and it will be your duty to enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong, and if you refuse to do that you will be a sinner too.

However, sometimes, things are not that much simple, e.g. when the sin that is commited if Zina, Allah says "*Let no man guilty of **adultery** or fornication marry and but a woman similarly guilty, or an Unbeliever: nor let any but such a man or an Unbeliever marry such a woman: to the Believers such a thing is forbidden.*" ... Be aware, as you may be able to change him and make him to pray, it is also possible that he will change you gradually so that you will not pray, hope not.

Such a marriage will have its own difficulties anyway, but it's up to you as what to choose. Remember that he will be the father of your children and your children will learn from him almost as much as will learn from you.

As a general rule, people are encouraged to marry those who are similar to themselves in faith, so I guess no one will encourage you for such a marriage unless you think both of you reside on one level of faith. For example, you love him so much and you know he doesn't pray, so **maybe** that he doesn't pray is not such a bad reputation in your viewpoint that will discourage you from this marriage. Think if he was a robber and you knew it, could you still think about marrying with him? I guess not. Anyway, you are the only person can judge yourself and your love toward him, maybe his honesty and other good reputations make you believe that if he doesn't pray, it is due to a misunderstanding of the religion and you can easily fix it for him and then he will be turned into a muslim many times better than those who pray days and nights ...

Better to consult with those who better knows you and him ...

and Allah knows best

Comment: We already have a son together and the thing is when we got married I also wasnt very much involved in religion but as years passed I started learning more about islam and that changed everything in me. I dont know what to do

Comment: @Mary, Oops, your saying "_**if** I am married_" made me think you are decideing whether to marry or not. In this case, no, there seems to be no reason for Allah to punish you for what you have done when you were not much familiar with religion, remember that Asiyah, the Pharaoh's wife, is amongst the most respectable women in Quran and in Islam.

Comment: However, you will need to do whatever you can to encourage your husband to become a good Muslim, by confessing your love together with concern toward him, like a mother do love and concern about her children. Afterall, if you love him and want him to be safe and happy for some tens of years in Dunya, sure it won't easy for you to find him being punished and regretfull for thousands of years in the Hereafter.

Answer (score 1):

If he says that he will start praying. If you marry with him then its better for you and also for him because for this he start praying and all the rewards are also going to her. Its good thing of you and also best for him.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum,

Few years ago I wasn't doing salat. That time I was already married to a beautiful wife and had our first born daughter entering 2 years of age. My wife and I was occasionally having fight over some ridiculous things back then and I over-reacted and almost hit her numerous times. Every time when this happen, our daughter will cry. I always have that intention to start praying and even tried a few times in my teenage years but never committed to it. My wife never stop to do salat in front of me and every time after prayer she will pray to Allah that I will one day open my heart to do salat too. The day that I decided to pray was right after we had a big fight on the previous night. I felt I was wrong and I felt something is missing after all those fights that we had. I don't know what to do and I don't know who to turn to because I know I'm responsible for my own family but I'm not really doing my full responsibility.

Alhamdulillah, that day Allah shows me the path that I've already seen so many times before but I never really try to commit to it. Come to think of it, I'm crying because I felt that Allah loves me very much that He never stopped giving me hidayah. I feel like I don't deserve this much love from Allah because I have done many sins before. I feel like I don't deserve my wife that never stopped praying for me but I think that's how Allah shows me the path, by giving me a wonderful wife. She has been the one trying to guide and get guidance for me and now it's my turn to take back the responsibility. Today, Alhamdulillah we have 3 beautiful children, my first born is now 8 years old and we always ask her to pray together with us. I always perform 5 times salat a day since then and there are times when I went over the allocated period but I don't skip it (e.g I woke up late at 6:10a.m and over fajr allocated period but I still do the salat).

I'm sorry if this post is too long but I feel that your situation is similar to my old situation. I'm not suggesting that you may have to go through what we've gone through but I'm saying that you must never stop praying and try to always perform salat in front of your husband. Every time before you perform your salat, look at you husband and invite him to salat with you with a soft voice or just signal it to him in a playful manner. Just say something like "if only I have a imam here.. ". Take this as a challenge to you from Allah.

And to address whether you will be punished or not, Wallahu A'lam. [One of the names of Allah is Al 'Adl - The Utterly Just](https://wahiduddin.net/words/99_pages/adl_29.htm).